# VueJS - How to access mixin methods from directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Simple code:

```
Vue.mixin(
    {
        methods :
        {
            test ()
            {
                return 'test';
            }
        },
    }
);

Vue.directive('my-directive',
    {
        inserted (el)
        {
            this.test();
        }
    }
);
```

[Vue warn]: Error in directive my-directive inserted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined"

Comment: Try `Vue.test()`

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in directive my-directive inserted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue___default.a.test is not a function" ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vue.mixin(
    {
        methods :
        {
            test ()
            {
                return 'test';
            }
        },
    }
);

Vue.directive('my-directive',
    {
        inserted (el)
        {
            //
        },
        bind(el, binding, vnode)
        {
            vnode.context.test();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Vue instance to call a method on, and a directive does not have an associated instance. But if you don't need a *particular* instance (that is, if the method doesn't reference `this`), you can just create one on the fly:

```
Vue.directive('my-directive',
    {
        inserted (el)
        {
            new Vue().test();
        }
    } );
```

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way of doing this. In general, directives are not part of the Vue component hierarchy. You might consider just making it a generally-available function.

Comment: vnode.context.test(); - this solution.

Comment: @WatschoAiwasov You _can_ use `vnode.context` to get the vm, but that's not my answer. You can write up your own answer if that's the solution you prefer.